# passing JSON value in JavaScript data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have one external JavaScript file which returns PHP response as JSON and i tried and check and its output is as desired  i want to pass this data to datapoints of canvasjs

here is my json output checked and tested returning as desired by JavaScript

```
{ x: 1, y: 59 },{ x: 2, y: 93 },{ x: 3, y: 477 },{ x: 4, y: 506 }
```

being stored in sthtml variable. 
here is that part of code

```
var html = '';
var sthtml = '';
var ndhtml = '', downlo;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    z = i + 1;
    downlo = data[i];
    html += '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + z + '</td></tr>';
    sthtml += '' + downlo.stchart + '';
    ndhtml += '' + downlo.ndchart + '';
}
$('#down-btn').html(html);
```

now i am passing this sthtml and ndhtml variable value to in page javascript with this ndhtml and sthtml. i tried ''+sthtml+'' and all other probable values but data is not returning and my graph is blank

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var sthtml = [];
    var ndhtml = [];
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        axisY: {},

        data: [{
            dataPoints: [sthtml]
        }, {
            dataPoints: [ndhtml]
        }],

        legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            itemclick: function(e) {
                chart.render();
            }
        }
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
```

i think when i load the page that time its empty and later these values are populated when users submit form so we need to update these again through some push

any help will be useful how can i pass sthtml and ndhtml values in above JavaScript datapoints

Comment: What are these lines: `sthtml += '' + downlo.stchart + '';` supposed to do according to you?

Comment: @Glubus its increases and adds the value so that it becomes like that after loop output is like { x: 1, y: 59 },{ x: 2, y: 93 },{ x: 3, y: 477 },{ x: 4, y: 506 }

Comment: Please refer to `CanvasJS.Chart` and check their examples

Comment: @PankajMakwana thanks for your idea. they have all external json data file like some .php and they are returning through function and calling them again. my question is why '+sthtml+' wont work. the value is already there and its already initialised so it must be pushed . i think when i load the page that time its empty and later these values are populated when users submit form so we need to update these again through some push

Comment: You are not sending JSON data, just concatenating string and passing it to Canvas.chart library.

Comment: Why are you setting your variable as an array in your JavaScript? Reset your **ndhtml** and **sthtml** as string. I hope it will work.

Comment: @PankajMakwana yes json data is already coming and formated so i just need to concatenate

Comment: @KeshariNandan tried setting like var sthtml ='';
  var ndhtml =''; but did not work

Comment: create a json format required for chart and put it into it

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var sthtml = '';
    var ndhtml = '';
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        axisY: {},

        data: [{
            dataPoints: [sthtml]
        }, {
            dataPoints: [ndhtml]
        }],

        legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            itemclick: function(e) {
                chart.render();
            }
        }
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
```

Inside onload function you are setting your variable as array but if you read the documentation on it requires a Joson data

```
data: [
        {
            type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 71 },
                { x: 20, y: 55 },
                { x: 30, y: 50 },
                { x: 40, y: 65 },
                { x: 50, y: 95 },
                { x: 60, y: 68 },
                { x: 70, y: 28 },
                { x: 80, y: 34 },
                { x: 90, y: 14 }
            ]
        }
        ]
```

Inside the data object you need an dataPoints object, Inside the dataPoints object your json data should go. Try this I hope it will work.

Comment: I can not see anything in the link you provided. @hareom

Comment: upload any image. u can see. canvas js is in same page and other js is in script721.js

Comment: Are you keeping your both JavaScript code in different files. It seems from the code you provided, your both javascript files are not connected. Can you please provide your html, php and full javascript code.

Comment: thx for reply.what do u mean by connected. its not database which require seperate connection. it does automatically. i will update u if i could solve . mostly i will

Comment: Connected means they are not in the same file, or they are not talking with each other. That's why you are not getting any data. And second thing after **onload** function your variable **sthtml** and **ndhtml** are set to null, I think that is the reason you are not getting any data into your chart. Look into that and try again I think it will work. And I know that all javascript code are included into html automatically if the they are included correctly.

Comment: tthx .it will definitely going to be helpful. i will update once done. by the way you have nice name